# Uploading image to a server

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Could someone please suggest a good tutorial on how to upload an image from my iPhone application, to a server programmatically?

Comment: [This one](http://stevegood.org/blog/uploading_an_image_from_ios_5) seems fairly simple.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend the following networking library

[AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use the ASIHTTP Library for doing this. The sample code which comes with the library also has the appropriate examples. The library can be downloaded here : http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ .

Comment: Has anyone read this post: "Please note that I am no longer working on this library - you may want to consider using something else for new projects.". This is about ASIHTTP. And look Last updated: 15th May 2011. This is a good library, but it has been deprecated.

Answer (score -1):

### Process 1:

- Grab the [ASIHTTPRequest](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/tree/master/Classes) api and add it to your project. see documentation [here](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions).
- import ***ASIFormDataRequest.h*** into your class and include the delegate

Use it as

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL  URLWithString:@"upload_url"]];
request.delegate = self;
[request setFile:@"your_image_name.jpg" forKey:@"photo"];
 // or [request setFile:@"your_image_name.jpg" withFileName:@"image_name_for_server.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"photo"];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

To get acknowledgement implement delegate methods, like

```
- (void)uploadRequestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
  NSLog(@"File upload successful"); 
}

- (void)uploadRequestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{ 
  NSLog(@" Error: file upload failed. Issue: \"%@\"",[[request error] localizedDescription]); 
}
```

**N.B.:** 
If you face the ARC problem, then simply goto the Xcode's ***File -> Refactor*** and select ***Convert to Objective-C ARC...***

OR

Goto ***Project -> Targets -> Built Phases -> Compile Sources***, select the Files and double click on the selected files. Write ***-fno-objc-arc***.

### Process 2:

An up-to-date way of doing so is using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/Getting-Started-with-AFNetworking). API can be download from [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/zipball/master)

To upload image, write

```
//Create http client
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"/*server_url*/"]];
//convert image to data
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"your_image_name.jpg"], 0.5/*this is compressionQuality, 0.5 will reduce the image into half*/);

// for PNG image, NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(([UIImage imageNamed:@"your_image_name.png"]); // it doesn't support compression

//add image data to the request
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                                     path:@"/upload"
                                                               parameters:nil
                                                constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData)
                                                                           {
                                                                              [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData 
                                                                                                          name:@"image_name_for_server" 
                                                                                                      fileName:@"image_name_for_server.jpg" 
                                                                                                      mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
                                                                           }
                              ];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
                                     {
                                       //this where you can monitor your upload progress
                                       NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
                                     }
];

[httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
```

Comment: Usage of ASIHTTPReqest is no longer advised. [AFNetworking](http://afnetworking.com) is the best alternative and is under active development.

Comment: @ user1763532, advised by whom? What is your reference? Yes, there are more than one alternatives. That doesn't mean you CANNOT use it. So why down vote? Is my answer wrong or is the answer inappropriate?

Comment: The answer is inappropriate, hence the down vote. If you checked your own sources you would see that the developer **himself** has advised using other frameworks. `Please note that I am no longer working on this library - you may want to consider using something else for new projects. :)`, taken from the documentation you linked to which hasn't been updated since May 2011. ASIHTTPRequest will no longer be up-to-date for future versions of iOS, suggesting that developers should use this outdated framework in new projects is irresponsible.

Comment: @ user1763532, thank you for your generosity. I wasn't aware of my irresponsibility.